# converting piece of javascript code to php

Tags: javascript, php

HI i am trying to convert javascript code to php.below is the javascript code

```
<script>

 var prefs = '["w",32,"r","s",2,"w",65,"w",26,"w",45,"w",24,"w",40,"s",2]';
var si = "hellocode";
var sig = (si + "").split("");

          function swap(arr, b) {
              l3 = arr[0];
              l4 = arr[b % arr.length];
              arr[0] = l4;
              arr[b] = l3;
              return arr
          }

          var cmd = JSON.parse(prefs||'["r","r"]');

          cmd.forEach(function (c, i) {
            if (typeof c !== "string") {
              return;
            }
            switch (c) {
            case "r":
              sig = sig.reverse();
              break;
            case "s":
              sig = sig.slice(cmd[i+1]);
              break;
            case "w":
              sig = swap(sig, cmd[i+1]);
              break;
            }
          });

</script>
```

What i have tried so far in php

```
<?php

$prefs = '["w",32,"r","s",2,"w",65,"w",26,"w",45,"w",24,"w",40,"s",2]';
$si = "hellocode";
$arr = str_split($si);
$sig = implode(',', $arr);


          function swap($arr, $b) {
              $cool = explode(",",$arr);
              $l3 = $cool[0];
              $l4 = $cool[$b % length($cool)];
              $cool[0] = $l4;
              $cool[$b] =$l3;
              return $cool;
          }
  //   $cool  = json_decode($prefs||'["r","r"]'); 
  //now i am struck with converting $prefs to array

$i=0;
foreach($cool as $c)
{

// how to get type of string here ?
// And what does slice function do ?
}
```

I got struck in 2nd part ? please see the comments and some experts in js to php ..guide me please.:)

Comment: http://us3.php.net/is_string to check if a variable is a string; array.slice, anyway, returns you the elements of an array inclued between the two parameters. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp (sorry for w3school). If you omit the second parameter, it will take from start to the end of the array. That is, if you slice an array from 1, it will return you all the elements from 1 to the end of array (to array.length). array.slice equivalent in php is, actually, the function array_slice: http://us1.php.net/array_slice

Comment: hey thanks :) how to convert $prefs to array ?

Comment: well, I'm not a god in json, but since it's a json string you should have the solution by using json_decode! http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you have [`is_string`](https://www.php.net/is_string) to check if a variable is a string.

[`slice`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_slice.htm) extracts a part of an array (in JS), the PHP pendant is [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-slice.php) when working with arrays or [`substr`](https://www.php.net/substr) when working with strings.

You found [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) already, so just take a look at the examples in the manual.
You max have to split `prefs||'["r","r"]'` into an `if-else` to check if `prefs` isn't empty, but i don't know how PHP handles the or-operator in this case.

To convert the `.forEach` from JS to PHP, i wouldn't go for a `foreach(...)`, as you won't have access to `i` as in the JS callback. Utilize a simple for-loop here.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cool); $i++) { /*....*/ }
```

Comment: hey thanks :) what does ||'["r","r"]');  do here ? json_decode gets error

Comment: Just edited it. JS treats it this way: if prefs doesnt exist, then take `'["r","r"]'` as input.

Comment: It accesses the array `cmd` with an index of `i+1` (without incrementing `i`). You would convert it by writing `$cool[i+1]`, as long as you have some variable `i`, preferably from a loop as JS does it - try reading up on [JavaScripts .forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)